# enforcing FTPS for Azure AppService WebApp

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

for deployment or downloading web application logs both FTP & FTPS can be used. I need to ensure that user can connect **only using FTPS**. Currently, it's up to user whether he/she uses FTP or FTPS. So, how do I strictly enforce FTPS for my AZure AppService WebApp?

There is documentation on enforcing HTTPS but nothing on enforcing FTPS.

Answer (score 3):

there is currently no option to disable FTP and enable FTPS in Azure websites, you can check this link: [CLosing FTP for PCI DSS Compliance and using only FTPS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/80586791-2799-4288-859a-e696d459572e/closing-ftp-for-pci-dss-compliance-and-using-only-ftps?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) for details.

Also you could vote in the link below to request for this feature: [Option to disable FTP (and force FTPS) in Azure Web Apps](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/8211222-option-to-disable-ftp-and-force-ftps-in-azure-we)

Comment: Thanks Steven. I voted for it. I am surprised why this is not being done. It's a big security loop hole.

Answer (score 2):

As of May 8th, 2018, you can now require FTPS or completely disable FTP/FTPS. The FTP access options are located on the Application Settings blade.

[Web Apps making changes to FTP deployments](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/05/08/web-apps-making-changes-to-ftp-deployments/)